# Создание роли не влияет на доступность таблиц для пользователя

Tags: hadoop

Ищу разрешение проблемы (или хотя бы людей, столкнувшихся с подобной проблемой).
Есть Impala с Sentry, интерфейс через Hue, "нужно создать пользователя и выдать ему права на селект из определенной схемы" - вроде бы все просто.
Проблема заключается в том, что действия не приводят к результату.

1. Создаем роль и даем ее группе.
   `--CREATE ROLE tezd_role;
   --GRANT select ON schema tezd_schema TO ROLE tezd_role;
   --GRANT ROLE tezd_role TO GROUP tezd_group;`
2. Создаем в ЛИНУКСЕ пользователя и группу, и связываем их
   `sudo adduser tezd_user
   sudo groupadd tezd_group
   sudo usermod -a -G tezd_group tezd_user`

Это мы делаем после того, как я прочитал, что одних "внутренних" (CDH-шных) пользователя и группы недостаточно, нужно иметь такие же в в самой системе.

Итого, что мы получаем? Пользователя и группу в ОСи, пользователя и группу в импале. Грантанутые права (роль) для группы, с которой связан пользователь.

Но после всех процедур пользователь так и не имеет возможности селектить таблицу.

Кроме того, только что созданный пользователь имеет доступ к запуску самой импалы (доступ к интерфейсу, select 1), хотя вначале (при создании) я вообще не включаю пользователя ни в одну группу. Это выглядит так, что настройки групп, ролей и доступов через интерфейс Hue вообще никак не влияет на реальные настройки прав и доступов.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте связан ли HUE с Sentry.

В Веб интерфейсе:  **HUE -> Configuration -> Sentry Service** нужно поставить галку на службу Sentry. Потребуется перезапуск службы.

Можете так же попробовать сделать селект не через HUE, но через beeline из операционной системы, предварительно получив тикет нужного пользователя.

- kinit tezd_user
- beeline
- beeline> !connect
  jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/default;principal=hive/hostname@REALM
- beeline> select * ...